Replacing clock crystal with signal generator
I have this blob chip module that I'm reverse-engineering, that ran off a 12 MHz crystal. In getting the module out I broke the crystal.
It was a two pin through hole component. Big orange blob marked with "12.0M". Currently, it's smashed into multiple pieces.
Is it possible to run the module off of a signal generator instead? I have heard that crystal oscillators like nice clean sinewaves, but unfortunately my signal generator can only output squarewaves.
If it's possible, what's your best guess on which of the two pins should I connect it to? They are labeled "OSO" and "ISO" on the carrier (not the usual "XIN" and "XOUT").

dragoncoder047 - Thanks for giving more details about the damaged component. I've put that information into the question & deleted the comment (as it's obsolete after copying the info into the question). || Can you add a photo of the broken component into the question, just for completeness? (Max photo filesize = 2MB; reduce the resolution & crop to make the photo a sensible size; press Ctrl+G when editing to start the image upload dialog.) That new description almost certainly means it's not a crystal, as explained in an answer, but a photo always helps. TY

@SamGibson the component is smashed... a photo would be next to useless in determining what it actually is! Although GodJihyo got it close with a 2 pin "orange blob" resonator -- mine was not so tall but mostly the same.

Your description sounds more like a ceramic resonator, perhaps something like this.
Those need to be connected to an oscillator, the resonator itself is just the frequency determining part, so your module will have an oscillator circuit built into it.
You should be able to feed the module a low level 12 MHz signal, it shouldn't take very much, maybe a few millivolts. If all you have available is a square wave signal the oscillator may work with it, if not and you do have to use a sine wave you could filter the square wave to get a sine wave. An LC filter should work, there are online apps to calculate the values needed, and you can simulate the filter with a square wave input in something like LTspice to see how well it works. Even an RC filter might be enough to get it working.

How is a resonator circuit different from a crystal oscillator circuit? The datasheet for the component you linked even includes an oscillator consistent with what I've seen for crystals -- inverting amplifier, 1M bias resistor, and two 10-50pF load caps

@dragoncoder047 Yes, they're pretty much the same as a crystal oscillator. Same basic idea except they use a ceramic material instead of quartz.
